# Is there any way to simplify this foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'd like to know if there is any way to simplify this.

It basically decodes a JSON API to array, then add each `value` from the objects to `$utxos` array.

This is what I actually have and would like simplified, if possible:

```php
$utxos = array();
$unspent = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://blockchain.info/unspent?active=1LaiteuxHEH4GsMC9aVmnwgUEZyrG6BiTH"), true)["unspent_outputs"];
foreach ($unspent as $utxo) array_push($utxos, $utxo["value"]);
```

Comment: `$utxos = array_column($unspent, 'value')` would probably do what you want. Completely gets rid of the need for the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @B.Fleming This works perfectly, thank you! Happy to have learnt something new today.

Comment: @B.Fleming - If you manage to solve the problem please post a answer so this question will be easier to use for future users (Or Laiteux - can post own answer)

Comment: Simplify for what? Readability, maintainability, performance?

Comment: @k0pernikus Smaller, cleaner code, sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```php
$unspent = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://blockchain.info/unspent?active=1LaiteuxHEH4GsMC9aVmnwgUEZyrG6BiTH"), true)["unspent_outputs"];
$utxos = array_column($unspent, "value")
```

Thanks to [B. Fleming](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8698101/b-fleming)

Comment: Will do in 2 days! "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"